# What is the diagonal $U(1) \subset SU(2)$ and the diagonal $u(1) \subset su(2)$?

Tags: group-theory, lie-algebra, representation-theory

What is meant by the diagonal $U(1) \subset SU(2)$ and the diagonal $u(1)\subset su(2)$? I have read it above eqn. (10) in this paper http://arxiv.org/abs/0812.3572 but have also heard it mentioned in physics talks before.

We can choose the Pauli matrices $\sigma^1,\sigma^2,\sigma^3$ as a basis for the Lie algebra $su(2)$. Does this have something to do with $\sigma^3$ being the only one of these that is a diagonal matrix?

Comment: A "diagonal" for any embedding $X\subset Y$ usually means that $Y=X\times X$ and that the map is $x\mapsto(x,x)$. I don't know what $\mathfrak{u}(1)$ "diagonal" in $\mathfrak{su}(2)$ is supposed to be, can you give a reference where that terminology is used?

Comment: @ACuriousMind Hi thanks for the reply. I have read it above eqn (10) in this paper http://arxiv.org/abs/0812.3572 but have also heard it mentioned in physics talks before.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, of course, the "diagonal $U(1)$ symmetry inside $SU(2)$" just refers to the group of matrices that are diagonal. The $2\times 2$ matrices  that are diagonal are ${\rm diag}(a,b)$. Their belonging to $SU(2)$ means that $|a|^2=|b|^2=1$ – from the unitarity – and $ab=1$, from the special condition (unit determinant).

So the diagonal $SU(2)$ matrices are simply matrices of the form ${\rm diag}(\exp(i\phi),\exp(-i\phi))$, which form a group isomorphic to a $U(1)$ as announced in that paper.

Note that, as AcuriousMind pointed out, the term "diagonal subgroup" is usually used differently, as the subgroup isomorphic to $G$ of elements of the form $(g,g)$ inside a group $G\times G$.

Comment: Thanks. But how does the $\sigma^3$ Pauli matrix come into play? Doesn't this require that we fix $\phi=\pi$ such that we get $\text{diag}(1,-1)$. This is then no longer a $U(1)$ group is it? Since we have restricted to a particular element?

Comment: @user11128  - the general diagonal matrix ${\rm diag}(\exp(i\phi),\exp(-i\phi)$ is equal to $\exp(i\phi \sigma_3)$, that's how the third Pauli matrix enters.The exponential of a diagonal matrix is a diagonal matrix, so it doesn't matter whether you impose the diagonal condition on the group or the Lie algebra. $\sigma_3$ itself isn't in the $SU(2)$ group, it is not supposed to be. ThePauli matrices are the generators of the group i.e. they belong to the $su(2)$ Lie algebra. You have to exponentiate them with an imaginary coefficient to get elements of the Lie group, $\exp(i\sum v^j \sigma^j)$.

Comment: Thank you very much. One final question: in the paper I linked to, in equation (10), they build the moment maps $P_I$. Should the moment maps be in the Lie group or the Lie algebra?

Comment: $P_I$ are combinations of $t_I$ which are "generators", so all these objects are by definition in the Lie algebra. Moreover, I don't see them using the term "moment maps". They say, below eq 11 on the next page, that $P_I$ are charges associated with the gauging. "Charges", like "generators", also always refers to generators i.e. Lie algebra elements, not any Lie group elements.

Answer (score 0):

Your terminology is hard to comprehend. My understanding regarding your question goes as follow.

What we know is group $U(1)$ isomorphic to $SO(2)$-rotation in a 2D plane. On the other hand the Lie algebra of $SU(2)$ is same as of $SO(3)$. Which means $SU(2)$ is isomorphic (locally they have same Lie algebra) to $SO(3)$. 
One can write
\begin{equation}
SO(3) = 
\begin{bmatrix}
SO(2) & 0 \\
0 &  1
\end{bmatrix}
\end{equation}

This implies $SO(2)$ is a subgroup of $SO(3)$. Since $SU(2)$ is homomorphic to $SO(3)$. Consequently $SO(2)$ is diagonal to $SU(2)$, as shown.